# XAML Errors But Not

Tags: uwp-xaml

I did not have this problem on a previous project, but for some reason I am having it now, and I do not see why for the life of me.

I think it has something to do with my Text Boxes, but not sure what it is causing it.

When I create a XAML page, I get something like this:
[image: Screen with Error - Note the text boxes piled up in top left corner.]

But if I run the program on local machine and then stop it, the screen looks like this:
[image: No code changes, but error is gone.]

I don't know what to make of this.

```
<Page
    x:Class="DC11Rounds.Pages.Electrical.GeneratorNorthPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:DC11Rounds.Pages.Electrical"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/CustomStyles.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid Background="Black">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      Grid.Column="0">
            <RelativePanel Margin="25">
                <TextBlock Name="SpacerTextBlock"
                           Width="1"
                           RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                           Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBlock}">                    
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="AlarmTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.LeftOf="SpacerTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="SpacerTextBlock"
                           Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBlock}"
                           Width="125"
                           Text="Alarms">
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="AutoTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.LeftOf="AlarmTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="SpacerTextBlock"
                           Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBlock}"
                           Width="125"
                           Text="In Auto">
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="EquipmentTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.LeftOf="AutoTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="SpacerTextBlock"
                           Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBlock}"
                           Width="200"
                           Text="Equipment">
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="CoolantTempTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.RightOf="SpacerTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="SpacerTextBlock"
                           Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBlock}"
                           Width="125"
                           Text="Coolant Temp">
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="TankLevelTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.RightOf="CoolantTempTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="SpacerTextBlock"
                           Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBlock}"
                           Width="125"
                           Text="Tank Level">
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="TMS3000TextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.RightOf="TankLevelTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="SpacerTextBlock"
                           Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBlock}"
                           Width="125"
                           Text="TMS3000 Level">
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="GenFTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="EquipmentTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.Below="EquipmentTextBlock"
                           Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBlock}"
                           Width="200"
                           Text="Gen F">
                </TextBlock>
                <ToggleSwitch Name="GenFAutoToggleSwitch"
                              RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="AutoTextBlock"
                              RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenFTextBlock"
                              Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXToggleSwitch}"
                              OnContent="Yes"
                              OffContent="No"
                              IsOn="True">
                </ToggleSwitch>
                <ToggleSwitch Name="GenFAlarmToggleSwitch"
                              RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="AlarmTextBlock"
                              RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenFTextBlock"
                              Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXToggleSwitch}"
                              OnContent="Yes"
                              OffContent="No"
                              IsOn="True">
                </ToggleSwitch>
                <TextBox Name="GenFCoolantTempTextBox"
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="CoolantTempTextBlock"
                         RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenFTextBlock"
                         Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBox}" Width="125">
                </TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="GenFTankLevelTextBox"
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="TankLevelTextBlock"
                         RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenFTextBlock"
                         Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBox}" Width="125">
                </TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="GenFTMS3000TextBox"
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="TMS3000TextBlock"
                         RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenFTextBlock"
                         Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBox}" Width="125">
                </TextBox>
                <TextBlock Name="GenGTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="EquipmentTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.Below="GenFTextBlock"
                           Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBlock}"
                           Width="200"
                           Text="Gen G">
                </TextBlock>
                <ToggleSwitch Name="GenGAutoToggleSwitch"
                              RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="AutoTextBlock"
                              RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenGTextBlock"
                              Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXToggleSwitch}"
                              OnContent="Yes"
                              OffContent="No"
                              IsOn="True">
                </ToggleSwitch>
                <ToggleSwitch Name="GenGAlarmToggleSwitch"
                              RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="AlarmTextBlock"
                              RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenGTextBlock"
                              Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXToggleSwitch}"
                              OnContent="Yes"
                              OffContent="No"
                              IsOn="True">
                </ToggleSwitch>
                <TextBox Name="GenGCoolantTempTextBox"
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="CoolantTempTextBlock"
                         RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenGTextBlock"
                         Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBox}" Width="125">
                </TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="GenGTankLevelTextBox"
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="TankLevelTextBlock"
                         RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenGTextBlock"
                         Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBox}" Width="125">
                </TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="GenGTMS3000TextBox"
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="TMS3000TextBlock"
                         RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenGTextBlock"
                         Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBox}" Width="125">
                </TextBox>
                <TextBlock Name="GenR2TextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="EquipmentTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.Below="GenGTextBlock"
                           Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBlock}"
                           Width="200"
                           Text="Gen R2">
                </TextBlock>
                <ToggleSwitch Name="GenR2AutoToggleSwitch"
                              RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="AutoTextBlock"
                              RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenR2TextBlock"
                              Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXToggleSwitch}"
                              OnContent="Yes"
                              OffContent="No"
                              IsOn="True">
                </ToggleSwitch>
                <ToggleSwitch Name="GenR2AlarmToggleSwitch"
                              RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="AlarmTextBlock"
                              RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenR2TextBlock"
                              Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXToggleSwitch}"
                              OnContent="Yes"
                              OffContent="No"
                              IsOn="True">
                </ToggleSwitch>
                <TextBox Name="GenR2CoolantTempTextBox"
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="CoolantTempTextBlock"
                         RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenR2TextBlock"
                         Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBox}" Width="125">
                </TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="GenR2TankLevelTextBox"
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="TankLevelTextBlock"
                         RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenR2TextBlock"
                         Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBox}" Width="125">
                </TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="GenR2TMS3000TextBox"
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="TMS3000TextBlock"
                         RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenR2TextBlock"
                         Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBox}" Width="125">
                </TextBox>
                <TextBlock Name="GenHTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="EquipmentTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.Below="GenR2TextBlock"
                           Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBlock}"
                           Width="200"
                           Text="Gen H">
                </TextBlock>
                <ToggleSwitch Name="GenHAutoToggleSwitch"
                              RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="AutoTextBlock"
                              RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenHTextBlock"
                              Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXToggleSwitch}"
                              OnContent="Yes"
                              OffContent="No"
                              IsOn="True">
                </ToggleSwitch>
                <ToggleSwitch Name="GenHAlarmToggleSwitch"
                              RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="AlarmTextBlock"
                              RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenHTextBlock"
                              Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXToggleSwitch}"
                              OnContent="Yes"
                              OffContent="No"
                              IsOn="True">
                </ToggleSwitch>
                <TextBox Name="GenHCoolantTempTextBox"
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="CoolantTempTextBlock"
                         RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenHTextBlock"
                         Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBox}" Width="125">
                </TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="GenHTankLevelTextBox"
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="TankLevelTextBlock"
                         RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenHTextBlock"
                         Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBox}" Width="125">
                </TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="GenHTMS3000TextBox"
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="TMS3000TextBlock"
                         RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenHTextBlock"
                         Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBox}" Width="125">
                </TextBox>
                <TextBlock Name="GenJTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="EquipmentTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.Below="GenHTextBlock"
                           Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBlock}"
                           Width="200"
                           Text="Gen J">
                </TextBlock>
                <ToggleSwitch Name="GenJAutoToggleSwitch"
                              RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="AutoTextBlock"
                              RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenJTextBlock"
                              Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXToggleSwitch}"
                              OnContent="Yes"
                              OffContent="No"
                              IsOn="True">
                </ToggleSwitch>
                <ToggleSwitch Name="GenJAlarmToggleSwitch"
                              RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="AlarmTextBlock"
                              RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenJTextBlock"
                              Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXToggleSwitch}"
                              OnContent="Yes"
                              OffContent="No"
                              IsOn="True">
                </ToggleSwitch>
                <TextBox Name="GenJCoolantTempTextBox"
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="CoolantTempTextBlock"
                         RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenJTextBlock"
                         Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBox}" Width="125">
                </TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="GenJTankLevelTextBox"
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="TankLevelTextBlock"
                         RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenJTextBlock"
                         Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBox}" Width="125">
                </TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="GenJTMS3000TextBox"
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="TMS3000TextBlock"
                         RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="GenJTextBlock"
                         Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBox}" Width="125">
                </TextBox>
                <TextBlock Name="ASTInspectionsTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="AutoTextBlock"
                           RelativePanel.Below="GenJTextBlock"
                           Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXTextBlock}"
                           Width="275"
                           Margin="0,75,0,0"
                           Text="Required AST Inspections Complete">
                </TextBlock>
                <ToggleSwitch Name="ASTInspectionsToggleSwitch"
                              RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="CoolantTempTextBlock"
                              RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="ASTInspectionsTextBlock"
                              Style="{StaticResource XXXXXXToggleSwitch}"
                              OnContent="Yes"
                              OffContent="No"
                              IsOn="True"
                              Margin="0,75,0,0">
                </ToggleSwitch>
            </RelativePanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here is the custom styles ResourceDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="XXXXXXTitleTextBlock" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="XXXXXXListBoxButton" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="36"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="XXXXXXListBoxText" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="XXXXXXNotesTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="500"/>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50,0,0,0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="NotesButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50,0,0,0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="XXXXXXTextBlock" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50,25,0,0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="XXXXXXComboBox" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50,25,0,0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="XXXXXXTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50,25,0,0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="XXXXXXTimePicker" TargetType="TimePicker">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="ClockIdentifier" Value="24HourClock"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50,25,0,0"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Your description is not clear, I don't know what issue in your xaml.

Comment: While programming I see the top screen.  Normally I would see the bottom screen when I program, but for some reason it doesn't do it.  But if I run local machine it pops up just fine.

Comment: @CET I still could not understand what your question is. Please provide more detailed information, you also could record a video to introduce the question that you faced.

Comment: The question is why won't my XAML preview show the text boxes when I add it?  I am using the same dictionary that I had used on another project and when I added a text box to it, it showed up on the screen perfectly.  On this project, when I add a text box, I get a text box in the top left corner of the screen.  But if I run the app on my local machine, when I stop the project it appears like it should.  I just do not understand why I do not see it like I should when I initially add it.

Comment: Added the ResourceDictionary to the original post.

Comment: @CET I copied your XAML code into my project to test, it worked well. The XAML designer showed all controls correctly. Have you tried to test your code on another machine? Sometimes, the visual studio XAML designer doesn't show correctly that because your computer doesn't have enough memory or other non-programming issues.

Comment: Interesting since the computer I am now using is better than the one I was previously using.  IDK.

Comment: Also, the original UWP app works fine on the same computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to do with minimum target value.  Once changed it fixed it.